# Problemas no goto em batch

Tags: batch, goto

Eu sou iniciante em `batch` e estou tentando criar um programa de despertador bem simples. O usuário deverá colocar o tempo que deseja que o despertador toque e o programa irá verificar o horário do computador. Caso o horário seja o mesmo do definido, o programa imprimirá "BEEP!". Este é meu código:

```
@echo off

set /p %tempoDefinido%=Defina um tempo para o alarme: 

:wait
if %time:~0,8% equ %tempoDefinido% (echo BEEP!) else (goto wait)
pause
```

O problema aqui é que o programa não volta para o `:wait`. Ele simplesmente continua até o `pause` e fecha. O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu erro foi não ter definido a variável %tempoDefinido%. Não se usa porcentagem na hora de definir a variável só na hora de verificar seu conteúdo. Quando acontece o IF ele compara uma variável existente "%temp% com uma variável não existente %tempoDefinido% isso cause um erro fazendo com que o if seja ignorado e passe direto para o pause.

Então ao invés de:

```
set /p %tempoDefinido%=Defina um tempo para o alarme:
```

Use:

```
set /p tempoDefinido=Defina um tempo para o alarme:
```

Considere fazer algo assim:

```
@echo off

set /p tempoDefinido=Defina um tempo para o alarme: 

:wait
cls
echo.
echo Hora atual: %time:~0,8% Alarme: %tempoDefinido%
if %time:~0,8% equ %tempoDefinido% (echo BEEP!) else (timeout /t 1 > nul & goto wait)

echo.
pause
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido desse detalhe, obrigado mesmo. Funcionou aqui <3

Answer (score 1):

Algumas opções para sonorizar o alarme:

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cls & title nul & title Alarme^!!

echo/ & set /p "alarme= [!time:~0,-6!] Defina um tempo para o alarme : "

:wait
echo/!time:~0,-6! | findstr /bl !alarme! >nul || goto :wait 
for /f %%i in ('forfiles /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo/0x07"')do echo/ & echo/ Hora certa: !time:~,8! ^| Beep^^!! %%i
>nul %__appdir__%pathping.exe 127.1 -n -q 1 -p 600 & %__appdir__%rundll32.exe %__appdir__%cmdext.dll,MessageBeepStub
>nul %__appdir__%pathping.exe 127.1 -n -q 1 -p 600 & %__appdir__%timeout -t -01 & endlocal & exit /b
```

---

Comment: Obrigado, isso vai ser útil no futuro mas por enquanto eu não sei nem usar o "for" kkkk.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 com mais tempo na sequência vou por um descritivo sobre a ação do for!